# What's the formula behind these two stock trading scenarios?

Tags: stocks, rate-of-return, compound-interest

Let's say I have $10,000 in my account.

Scenario 1:

If I make 10 trades in a year and each trade I position size using only 25% every time and exit the trade after a 10% gain, my account would grow by 40% at the end of the year.

So --

```
10 trades
10% gain
25% position size
= 40% return
```

This example was taken from the book "Trade Like an O'Neil Disciple" -- [image]

Scenario 2:

Similar to the above except I take a smaller gain and therefore increase my number of trades.

So --

```
17 trades
8% gain
25% position size
= 40% return
```

This is with compounding of course.

Questions:

- What's the formula behind this? I would like to know so I could plug in some different numbers.
- Suppose I lower my position size to 20% or 15%... how many trades would it now take to get to a 40% return?
- Suppose I wanted a 50% or even a 100% return at the end of the year... what should my position size be and how many trades would that take?
- Suppose I take a bigger gain each time (15% or 20%), what should my position size be if I still want a 40% return? How about for a 50% or 100% return?

Comment: I don't think that your math is right.  I come up with 28% compounded for the first scenario and it would take 13 trades to exceed this (the second scenario).  I'll leave it to someone else to provide formulas for this.

Comment: @BobBaerker this is taken from a book (Trade Like an O'Neil Disciple) so the math i'm assuming has been checked multiple times -- https://i.imgur.com/dTqv5Gj.png

Comment: @Solarflare 2nd calculation comes from here -- https://i.imgur.com/egoI9DB.png it's a slide from mark minervini's workshop last year. at the bottom you see the number of trades needed (red color) if you want 30%/40%/etc return with an 8% gain on a 25% position size

Comment: If you invest 25% of your money, you make 25% of your profit. As in 159% * 25% = 40%. That's what the book means. It doesn't want you to reinvest only 25% of the returns (which is probably what Bob Baerker used to calculate to get to the 28%).

Comment: @Solarflare my interpretation of the book is if you invest 100% of your capital on a trade and take profits at 10% and do this 9 more times for a total of 10 times, you will end up with a 159% return at the end of the year. of course this unrealistic (crazy to put ALL of your money on a single trade) so the author reduced the position size to 25% and your return at the end of the year would then be 40%.

Comment: The 2 calculations you provided do 2 different things: the 1st scenario (book) takes 2500 of your 10k and invests it and uses all profits to reinvest, e.g. in the 2nd trade, you use 2500+250=2750 to invest. The 2nd scenario (mark minervinis workshop) uses only 25% of the profits (as it only uses 25% of the current total amount), e.g. (with 10%), the 2nd trade would use 2500+250/4=2562,50 to reinvest. That will obviously give you 2 different results, and you cannot mix those 2 sources/explanations/calculations.

Comment: @Jay - Compounding doesn't work that way when a fractional investment is used. It's not linear.  10% gain per trade on $2,500 would provide the same 159% return as 10% per trade on $10k.  However, if you are investing 25% of the cash but the principal is $10k plus the gains, the return is much less than 1/4 because 3/4 of the money is not being invested so it's a drag on the compounding.  If someone doesn't show up with a clever compounding formula explanation tomorrow, I'll post actual numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of confusion about what the original author describes, and I don't have the slides, so I'll go by the provided wording:

You use only 25% of your capital for the first trade, which means 2500 $. You exit at 10% gain, which gives you 2500 * 110% = 2750 $. Now you have 10250 $!

For the further trades, it is questionable if you continue to use 25% of your *original* capital (which is still and will always be 2500 $), or 25% of your current capital at that time (which is 10250 $ * 25% = 2562.50 $  which Bob called 'compounding'). The latter will result in a tad more gains from the second trade, because you invest a little bit more, and that little bit continues to grow a bit with every trade.

If you look at the second example, you 'grind finer', by doing more trades for less gains, linearly resulting in the same overall total, but - because of the compounding effect - a little bit more at the end.

Continuing this approach, you can 'grind finer and finer', up to an infinitesimal small gain (and a corresponding infinite number of trades and compounding), which will give you a limit for the maximum achievable with this technique.
I don't have the formula ready right now, but it is something with `Capital*e^(.../...)` as far as I remember.

Comment: My interpretation is that the size of each succeeding investment increases.  IOW, 25% of total principal after each winning trade.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first scenario is easy.  If you use all proceeds and earn 10% per trade, it's (1.1^10 * 10,000). This can be seen with the following raw data:

```
   (A)        (B)        (C)
 10,000     11,000      10.00%
 11,000     12,100      21.00%
 12,100     13,310      33.10%
 13,310     14,641      46.41%
 14,641     16,105      61.05%
 16,105     17,716      77.16%
 17,716     19,487      94.87%
 19,487     21,436     114.36%
 21,436     23,579     135.79%
 23,579     25,937     159.37%
    
 Gain = 15,937  15,937/10,000 = 159.37%

 (A) is the principal invested
 (B) is the total capital  
 (C) is the cumulative percent gain
```

I don't know enough about accounting to provide a compounding formula for only investing 25% of the gains.  Perhaps someone else will offer that.  What I can provide is the raw numbers:

```
 (A)       (B)    (C)     (D)
            
 2,500     250  10,250   2.50%
 2,563     256  10,506   5.06%
 2,627     263  10,769   7.69%
 2,692     269  11,038  10.38%
 2,760     276  11,314  13.14%
 2,829     283  11,597  15.97%
 2,899     290  11,887  18.87%
 2,972     297  12,184  21.84%
 3,046     305  12,489  24.89%
 3,122     312  12,801  28.01%
        
 Gain = 2,801    2,801/10,000 = 28.01%

 (A) is the principal invested
 (B) is the gain per trade
 (C) is the total capital  
 (D) is the cumul percent gain based on $10k of principal
```

So unless I've misunderstood the question, this scenario offers a yield of 28.01%, not 40%.